# Why does this code not properly center scene when doing UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, centering, uipangesturerecognizer

I am a beginner developing a program for the AppStore using Xcode's sprite kit. I made a 'test' program so I can try out new things before adding it to my game. Right now I am fiddling around with swiping a scene - I have an SKNode (called "background") where I am adding several children as SKSpriteNodes. One sprite node is visible on the initial scene (the center, position 160,240), and two more that are not visible: to the left of the scene (position -160,240), and to the right of the scene (position 480,240).

I would like my game to be able to swipe left or right, and when it swipes left or right, the view will auto-center itself (with animation) to one of the three SKSpriteNodes. My code using the UIPanGestureRecognizer to move the background node works properly, and my code for auto-centering the view works MOSTLY (background position set to 0,0 or -320,0 or +320,0), but sometimes it has a strange offset and doesn't completely center itself (for example, the background position will be 7,0 or -34,0 when I pan right or left). What am I doing wrong?

P.S: I am using code from RayWenderlich's "iOS Games" for the SKTMoveEffect. I also want to note that if I make the function f(t)=t, there is no problem (at least in my several tests), but f(t)=t^2 or anything else seems to have an issue; if it helps to see the code for this I can post it too

```
@implementation LTMyScene
{
    SKNode *background;
    SKSpriteNode *spaceship1, *spaceship2;
}
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        background=[SKNode node];
        [self addChild:background];
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
        myLabel.text = @"Hello, World!";
        myLabel.fontSize = 30;
        myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                       CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        [background addChild:myLabel];

        spaceship1=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship.png"];
        spaceship1.position=CGPointMake(-self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
        spaceship1.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
        [background addChild:spaceship1];

        spaceship2=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship.png"];
        spaceship2.position=CGPointMake(self.size.width*3/2, self.size.height/2);
        spaceship2.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
        [background addChild:spaceship2];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragPlayer:)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
}

-(void)dragPlayer: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    [[[self view] layer] removeAllAnimations];
    CGPoint trans = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
    SKAction *moveAction =  [SKAction moveByX:trans.x y:0  duration:0];
    [background runAction:moveAction];
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];


    if([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGFloat finalX=0;
        if (abs(background.position.x)<self.size.width/2) {
            finalX=0;
        } else if (abs(background.position.x)<self.size.width*3/2) {
            finalX=self.size.width*background.position.x/abs(background.position.x);
        }
        NSLog(@"%f",finalX);

        SKTMoveEffect *upEffect =
        [SKTMoveEffect effectWithNode:background duration:0.5
                        startPosition:background.position
                          endPosition:CGPointMake(finalX, 0)];

        upEffect.timingFunction = ^(float t) {
//            return powf(2.0f, -3.0f * t) * fabsf(cosf(t * M_PI * 1.0f)) //has bounce
//            return (-1.0f*t*t+1) //no bounce ... for parabola this is only solution with (1,0) and (0,1) as intercepts and vertex at (1,0)
            return (t*t)
            ;};

        SKAction *upAction = [SKAction actionWithEffect:upEffect];
        [background runAction:upAction];
    }
}
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",background.position.x,background.position.y);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that you are moving the larger background node with other nodes as its children. Keeping that in mind, the code you need to center on a specific node is:

```
_worldNode.position = CGPointMake(-(myNode.position.x-(self.size.width/2)), -(myNode.position.y-(self.size.height/2)));
```

The above assumes that your main background "canvas" is called `_worldNode` and your target node is a child of `_worldNode`